# Google Sheets Script .getValue() and .getDisplayValue() returning #REF For Some Reason

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had this function working before, but for some reason it is not working anymore.
[This is a picture of the three pieces of data I am trying to collect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qzL9.png) They have references to a couple other sheets in my file including some 'INDIRECT's. The following is the simple code I am trying to run to obtain the value of one of the pieces of data:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logKey).getSheetByName("Investing");
var value = ss.getRange("G2").getValue();
var formula = ss.getRange("G2").getFormula();
Logger.log("Value: " + value + "  Formula: " + formula);
```

... And this is the output:

> [16-10-06 09:50:04:531 EDT] Value: #REF!  Formula: =AD$2

As you can see from the output, it is successfully reading the cell from the spreadsheet, but it is not obtaining the value from the cell, just the formula. I don't understand why this is the case as in my sheet, the value it is trying to obtain is **not** '#REF!'.

As I said before, I had this general piece of code working before, but I must have changed something such that it broke what I am attempting to do.

Additional note: I am unsure if this code may be the culprit for some reason, even though it worked like this before. This is simply to convert columns numbers to row numbers form another sheet for easy copy and paste:

```
=INDEX(
  INDIRECT(
    CONCATENATE("QUOTES!",
      REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), ((ROW()-3)*5)+4), "[A-Z]+"),
      "4:", 
      REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), ((ROW()-3)*5)+4), "[A-Z]+")
    )
  ), 
  COUNT(
    INDIRECT(
      CONCATENATE("QUOTES!",
        REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), ((ROW()-3)*5)+4), "[A-Z]+"),
        "4:", 
        REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(ROW(), ((ROW()-3)*5)+4), "[A-Z]+")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Have you had any update since? And btw, you don't necessarily have to use Apps Script to test. When Apps Script reads #REF erroneously, `importrange` would too.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

To avoid the #REF! error, the formula should not be placed on the second row. It  could be placed on row 3 and below rows.

## Explanation

`ADDRESS(ROW(), ((ROW()-3)*5)+4)` on any cell of row 2 returns the following error message:

> Function ADDRESS parameter 2 value is -1. Valid values are between 1 and 18278 inclusive.

Comment: Sorry, that's not my problem. The formula works fine for me within the Google sheet, but only when I reference it in the script editor it returns #REF!. This can be seen from the first picture, the numbers exist in the sheet as they should. Only when I try to reference them in the script editor, it thinks they contain #REF! for some reason. You are correct that it shouldn't be in the second row and it isn't. It is on the rows 3 or greater.

Comment: The picture doesn't show row and column headers, in other words, there is not enough details to be able to reproduce the problem as you see it. Please create a demo spreadsheet, share it with anyone with the link for view only and add the link to your question.